# How to replace revoked certificate with self signed certificate on server and client?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have created a self signed certificate and wanted to replace revoked certificate with one I have created

Comment: Why? Why not get it signed?

Comment: Immediate requirement client side